# Get unexpected result while using Java 8 Lambda Expression

Tags: java, stream, distinct

I have changed my Test to make it reproduce easier:
Minimize Test

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestBean> obj_list = Arrays.asList(new TestBean("aa"), new TestBean("bb" ), new TestBean("bb")).stream()
                .distinct().map(tt -> {
                    tt.col = tt.col + "_t";
                    return tt;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(obj_list);

        List<String> string_obj_list = Arrays.asList(new String("1"), new String("2"), new String("2")).stream().distinct().map(t -> t + "_t").collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(string_obj_list);

        List<String> string_list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "2").stream().distinct().map(t -> t + "_t").collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(string_list);
    }
}
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
class TestBean {
    String col;
}
```

the result is below, the line one is abnormal for me to understand:

```
[TestBean(col=aa_t), TestBean(col=bb_t), TestBean(col=bb_t)]
[1_t, 2_t]
[1_t, 2_t]
```

----------original question is below -------------------------------

my logic step:

1. produce a list of stream
2. map each element to list stream
3. collect list stream to one stream
4. distinct element
5. map function apply to each element and collect the result to a list

however , the result does not do distinct logic (step 4) ,which is that i can not understand

```java
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<TestBean> stage1 = Arrays.asList(new TestBean("aa", null), new TestBean("bb", null), new TestBean("bb", null)).stream()
                .map(tt -> {
                    return Arrays.asList(tt);
                })
                .flatMap(Collection::stream).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Object> stage2 = stage1.stream().map(tt -> {
            tt.setCol2(tt.col1);
            return tt;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(stage1);
        System.out.println(stage2);

        List<TestBean> stage_all = Arrays.asList(new TestBean("aa", null), new TestBean("bb", null), new TestBean("bb", null)).stream()
                .map(tt -> {
                    return Arrays.asList(tt);
                })
                .flatMap(Collection::stream).distinct().map(tt -> {
                    tt.setCol2(tt.col1);
                    return tt;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(stage_all);
    }
}
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
class TestBean {
    String col1;
    String col2;
}
```

the result is

```
[TestBean(col1=aa, col2=aa), TestBean(col1=bb, col2=bb)]
[TestBean(col1=aa, col2=aa), TestBean(col1=bb, col2=bb)]
[TestBean(col1=aa, col2=aa), TestBean(col1=bb, col2=bb), TestBean(col1=bb, col2=bb)]
```

line three is abnormal for me.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What Java version and implementation do you use?

Comment: Why are you turning a `Stream<TestBean>` into a `Stream<List<TestBean>>` (with each list having exactly one element), only to turn it back into a `Stream<TestBean>` with the `flatMap` operation?

Comment: 1. java 8 and lombok package should be available for this test

Comment: 2. In my code logic, Stream<TestBean> may produce a Stream<List<TestBean> (with each list may have more than one element, but in this test, it does not exists).

Comment: Don't modify the elements during intermediate processing of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct()` operation is filtering the set of items in the stream using `Object.equals(Object)`.

However you are mutating the items as they are streamed - **a very bad idea for `Set` operations** - so in theory it is possible in your runs that the first `TestBean(col=bb)` is changed to `TestBean(col=bb_t)` before the final `TestBean(col=bb)` is handled by distinct(). Therefore at that moment there are 3 unique items in the stream seen by the `distinct()` step and the last `.map()` sees all three items.

You can verify by re-processing the stream without the ".map()" side effect or add `.distinct()` after `.map()`.

Takeaway from this: Don't use distinct() or other set like operations on data structures that change fields used in `equals()` or `hashCode()` as this gives misleading / duplicates into `set.add()` operations. This is where Java records are useful as they cannot be changed and would eliminate errors from these type of side-effects:

```
record TestBean(String col) {}
```

**Example**

The `@EqualsAndHashCode` tag on `TestBean` is generating the `equals` and `hashCode` calls which are essential for `Set` / `distinct()` operations to work. If the hashcode/equals changes after adding an item, the set won't work properly as it fails to match up the previous element as being a duplicate of a newly added element. Consider this simpler definition of TestBean which add same instance 5 times:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    class TestBean {
        String col;
        TestBean(String col) {
            this.col = col;
        }
        // This is bad choice hashCode as it changes if "col" is changed:
        public int hashCode() {
            return col.hashCode();
        }
    }
    Set<TestBean> set = new HashSet<>();
    TestBean x = new TestBean("bb");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("set.add(x)="+set.add(x));
        System.out.println("set.size()="+set.size());
        // Comment out next line or whole hashCode method:
        x.col += "_t";
    }
}
```

Run the above which adds same element to a set 5 times. You will see that `set.size()` may be 5 not 1. Comment out the line which causes the hashcode to change - or the `hashCode()` method, and `set.size()=1` as expected.

Comment: As you mentioned, the first `TestBean(col=bb)` may change to `TestBean(col=bb_t)` before the final `TestBean(col=bb)` is handled by distinct().   So i changed my last TestBean from `bb` to `bb_t`, what  i expect  is a two-element list. However the result is a three-element list.

Comment: @imlegend Fiddling with the input data and hoping the evaluation is in a particular order isn't a good way to develop or test. You should be able to confirm what I said as mentioned above: "verify by re-processing the stream without the ".map()" side effect or add .distinct() after .map()."

Comment: Sets (and maps) often use hashcode to split items into internal tables. If key's hashcode() changes after insertion then the set does not move a previously hashed item. This means it may still appear to have 3 distinct items.

Comment: Thanks a lot，I already notice the problems and will not make the same mistake again. I just want to know the real processing flow.

Comment: I've added an example which might help demonstrate the issue you are seeing.